# "Package dependencies cannot be resolved" when installing codecs

Tags: dependencies, codecs

I'm trying to install some additional codecs, but it always throws the following error:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gstreamer1.0-libav:i386: Depends: libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.13) but 6:9.13-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                         Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.13-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                         Depends: libavutil52 (>= 6:9.1-1) but 6:9.13-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                         Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
                         Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.40.0-2 is to be installed
```

I recently installed the  ppa:mc3man/trusty-media PPA.

The output of `apt-cache policy libavcodec-extra-54`:

```
libavcodec-extra-54:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6:9.13-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
     6:9.13-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     6:9.11-2ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

What can I do about it?

Comment: Are you using a video/audio-related PPA, and what is the output of `apt-cache policy libavcodec-extra-54`? (Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/489664/edit) your question and paste the output there).

Comment: thank you for your comment. I've applied the edits you suggested

Comment: Ah, I forgot security updates use that versioning format as well. Also, I can't install the i386 version as well, even though the version requirement is met (which I failed to notice earlier). I'll see if I can find something out.

Comment: My hunch was right. In Trusty (at least), the i386 version cannot be co-installed with the amd64 version. I'll be posting an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The `i386` version of `gstreamer1.0-libav` cannot be co-installed with the `amd64` (or any other architecture) version of the package. This is because at least one of the packages it depends on (`libopus0`) hasn't been marked as being co-installable with another architecture of the package. (See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec#Binary_package_control_fields) for the specifications of this). Because this hasn't been set, `apt` will refuse to install the `i386` version and the `amd64` version.

I would file a bug on the package [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/+source/opus), and link to that section of the spec. Note that the current version in Saucy and Trusty won't be changed (since this is bit of a major change), but the fix will be in Utopic.

Comment: It's possible that if `Multi-Arch: same` is added to libopus0 in the control file this can be resolved. I tried via my proposed media ppa & seems ok though would be hesitant to do so in a ppa that people use if not 100% correct for any reason. (trusty multimedia is my ppa). If you wish to test let me know though the proposed ppa is not for general use at all, would place in a temp standalone ppa for testing.

Comment: @doug: Yes, adding `Multi-Arch: same` would allow it to be installed. I'll be happy to test to see if it fixes it, as there may be other packages that need to be changed. (Note that I'll just be using the `--simulate` option of `apt-get` to see if it allows it.)

Comment: give it a little while to publish, if really ok I'll move to trusty multimedia. https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/opus-test

Comment: @doug: Yup, that fixed it. Do you want to go ahead and file the bug for the source package?

Comment: well it should be filed on current dev, 14.10, which I don't have atm, will in a week or so. Otherwise anyone on 14.10 feel free.